# Using bootstrap3, how do I move a container down to the middle of the page?

Tags: header, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, row, containers

HTML:

```
<header class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Left-half</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Right-half</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

LESS:

```
header {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
}
```

I've tried using "position: absolute;", which does move my header class down to where I want it, but then it squeezes the two columns onto the left half of my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change `top` to `margin-top` it will move your header down.

```
header {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25%;
}
```

It looks like 50% is causing too much margin, not sure if that is a Bootply issue.  25% looks more like half on Bootply (**[Demo Here](http://www.bootply.com/wRvPtQ1COb)**) though you can play around with that to fit your needs.

Comment: I'm happy that it works and I'm sad that I didn't try that haha. Regardless, thank you a ton!